# How to weight cols for each records using SQL only

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

In Postgresql, suppose I have a 2-col table containing 3 records, namely `tA`

```
id | col_A | col_B | type
1  | 1     | 2     | A  
2  | 3     | 4     | B
3  | 3     | 1     | A
```

and a table that contains column weights for each type, named `tB`

```
type | col   | weight
A    | col_A | 0.6
A    | col_B | 0.4
B    | col_A | 0.4
B    | col_B | 0.6
```

then I want to have a new table that has the same size as `tA`, but cols are weighted with `tB`. For example, where `id=1`, due to type `A`, hence `col_A*0.6`, `col_B*0.4`. The expected result is below

```
id | col_A | col_B | type
1  | 0.6   | 0.8   | A  
2  | 1.8   | 1.6   | B
3  | 1.2   | 0.4   | A
```

Currently, I wrote a SQL function to handle but I wonder if is there another way that can be done in SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed list of column names, you can `join`, then do conditional aggregation to weight to each value:

```
select a.id, 
    a.col_a * max(b.weight) filter(where b.col = 'colA') col_a,
    a.col_b * max(b.weight) filter(where b.col = 'colB') col_b,
    a.type
from ta a
inner join tb b using (type)
group by a.id
```

This would filter out rows on `ta` whose types do no exist in `tb`. If that’s a concern, you can use `left join` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table would be perfect for this considering how there may be more than two types in the future, possibly dozens? For this you want the `tablefunc` extension that comes with Postgres as there is no native support for it like can be found in MS SQL Server or Oracle.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
```

This makes the `crosstab` pivot table function available in your database.

With the assumption that your weights are `numeric` types that do not suffer from IEEE floating point accuracy issues:

```
SELECT tA.id
     , tA.col_A * ct.weight_A col_A
     , tA.col_B * ct.weight_B col_B
     , tA.type
  FROM tA
  JOIN crosstab('SELECT type, col, weight FROM tB ORDER BY type, col')
       AS ct(type text, weight_A numeric, weight_B numeric, weight_C numeric)
       USING (type)
 ORDER BY id
;
```

Change to `double precision` or `real` as wanted/needed. See that `SELECT` statement in the `crosstab` function? This basically says, the first column returned is your row identifier, your grouping. The second returned column are the names of the columns you want returned. The last is the value of the previous column. So `ct` becomes a virtual table that changes your `tB` table looking like this:

| type | col | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | col_A | 0.6 |
| A | col_B | 0.4 |
| B | col_A | 0.4 |
| B | col_B | 0.6 |

to look like this instead:

| type | weight_A | weight_B | weight_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.6 | 0.4 | [NULL] |
| B | 0.4 | 0.6 | [NULL] |

Note how `weight_C` never exists in the `tB` values? That's okay and useful. It means with a minor change to your query, you can add and remove columns to reflect the changing state of `tB`. You can add `weight_D` and `weight_E` return columns, for example. If they are not present in `tB`, they will remain NULL, but if you add the appropriate weights to `tB`, they will fill in automatically!

This computed table is what you join against to get your final answer.